# Powershell Add-Type CompilerParameters

Tags: powershell

Как использовать в Powershell `Add-Type -CompilerParameters`?

Я пытаюсь так:

```
$cp = [System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters]::new()
$cp.GenerateExecutable = $true
$cp.OutputAssembly = 'D:\test.exe'
$cp.GenerateInMemory = $false
$cp.CompilerOptions = "-optimize -target:exe"
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $CsCode -CompilerParameters $cp
```

Но это не работает, никаких сообщений об ошибках, но файл не создаётся.
А как правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что это потому, что `Add-Type` не передает `CompilerParameters` напрямую, а парсит и добавляет собственной магии:

---

- [AddType.cs#L916-L934](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/AddType.cs#L916-L934)

---

```
if (CompilerOptions != null)
{
    var arguments = ParseCompilerOption(CompilerOptions);

    HandleCompilerErrors(arguments.Errors);

    parseOptions = arguments.ParseOptions;
    compilationOptions = arguments.CompilationOptions.WithOutputKind(OutputAssemblyTypeToOutputKind(OutputType));
    emitOptions = arguments.EmitOptions;
}
else
{
    compilationOptions = GetDefaultCompilationOptions();
}

if (!IgnoreWarnings.IsPresent)
{
    compilationOptions = compilationOptions.WithGeneralDiagnosticOption(defaultDiagnosticOption);
}
```

Попробуйте так:

```
$cp = [System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters]::new()
$cp.CompilerOptions = '-optimize'

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $CsCode -OutputAssembly 'D:\test.exe' -OutputType ConsoleApplication -CompilerParameters $cp
```